# Notify or update salesforce records from external application

Tags: rest-api, api, streaming-api, external-app

As Integration part is new to me so, tried little demo project which gets the external data and creates the record in custom object or so from a button click. `Using HttpRequest method did all the API request.`

> My question here is, Is it possible to keep track of external
>   application so whenever the data is changed in external should reflect
>   in salesforce too or simply notify me in salesforce.

As far as I understood using `Streaming API` you can `notify external Application or salesforce if there is a change in Salesforce database` right?

Answer (score 1):

When external database changes, you want the same data to be synced in Salesforce.
So it should be the external system which should update salesforce about it/notify about it.

You cant use streaming API, because streaming API is for broadcasting changes of SF data change to external system and not vice versa.

You have 2 Options:

1. Poll external system periodically to get changed data
2. Or create a Listener in external system to send SF a platform event or call any salesforce rest endpoint about the changed data.

You can read more about the integration patterns here:
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/integration_patterns_and_practices.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Streaming API to get push notifications. Take a look to this link: [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm)

There you will find multiple examples and how to subcribe to the "events" in order for you to get the desire notifications.

On the section **How the Client Connects** on that documentnion you get a nice diagram with the process execution to connect to an event. [image]

On the [Code Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/api_streaming_code_examples.htm) section you can start looking to structures to accomplish what you want.